# EventSourceHandler being triggered by the wrong event?

Tags: java, spring-boot, axon

I am experiencing an issue where an event is being triggered that I would imagine shouldn't be.
I am playing with axon and am modeling a letter sending service based on letter sending events. My example is kind of trivial.

I have designed two input commands `ScheduleLetterCommand` which will "send a letter" in a few minutes...which allows the user to cancel it if they send another command `CancelLetterCommand` within that time period.

I am triggering commands via a REST API Controller...

What I am expecting to see is the log statements that say a letter is scheduled and cancelled if I were to schedule a letter and immediately cancel it within the next five minutes.

What I am curiously seeing is that the letter is scheduled successfully and I see the following log statements:

```
Received schedule command for letter id e6e037be-3b6d-4ae3-80cd-12426adcd526
LetterScheduledEvent e6e037be-3b6d-4ae3-80cd-12426adcd526 SCHEDULED
```

But when I cancel the letter I see this behavior:

```
LetterScheduledEvent e6e037be-3b6d-4ae3-80cd-12426adcd526 SCHEDULED
Received cancel command for letter id e6e037be-3b6d-4ae3-80cd-12426adcd526
Letter e6e037be-3b6d-4ae3-80cd-12426adcd526 cancelled CANCELLED
```

What am I missing here? Why is the `LetterScheduledEvent` handler being triggered again?

Here's my aggregate -

```java
public class Letter {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String letterId;
    private ScheduleToken scheduleToken;

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    protected Letter() {
        // Default constructor required by Axon Framework
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public Letter(ScheduleLetterCommand cmd, EventScheduler scheduler) {
        String id = cmd.getLetterId();
        log.info("Received schedule command for letter id {}", letterId);
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new LetterScheduledEvent(id, LetterEventType.SCHEDULED));
        this.scheduleToken = scheduler.schedule(Duration.ofMinutes(5), new BeginSendLetterEvent(id,LetterEventType.BEGIN_SEND));
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public void handle(CancelLetterCommand cmd, EventScheduler eventScheduler) {
        String letterId = cmd.getLetterId();
        log.info("Received cancel command for letter id {}", letterId);
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new LetterCancelledEvent(letterId, LetterEventType.CANCELLED));
        eventScheduler.cancelSchedule(scheduleToken);
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(LetterScheduledEvent event) {
        log.info("LetterScheduledEvent {} {}", event.getLetterId(), event.getEventType());
        this.letterId = event.getLetterId();
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(LetterCancelledEvent event) {
        log.info("Letter {} cancelled {}", event.getLetterId(), event.getEventType());
        scheduleToken = null;
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(BeginSendLetterEvent event) {
        log.info("Letter sending process started {} {}", event.getLetterId(), event.getEventType());
        //complicated letter sending processes...
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new LetterSentEvent(event.getLetterId(), LetterEventType.SENT));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(LetterSentEvent event) {
        log.info("Letter sent {} {}", event.getLetterId(), event.getEventType());
    }
}
```

And here's my events ->

```java
abstract class LetterMovementEvent(open val letterId: String, open val eventType: LetterEventType)

enum class LetterEventType {
    SCHEDULED,
    CANCELLED,
    BEGIN_SEND,
    SENT
}

data class LetterScheduledEvent(
        override val letterId: String,
        override val eventType: LetterEventType = LetterEventType.SCHEDULED
) : LetterMovementEvent(letterId, eventType)

data class LetterCancelledEvent(
        override val letterId: String,
        override val eventType: LetterEventType = LetterEventType.CANCELLED
) : LetterMovementEvent(letterId, eventType)

data class BeginSendLetterEvent(
        override val letterId: String,
        override val eventType: LetterEventType = LetterEventType.BEGIN_SEND
) : LetterMovementEvent(letterId, eventType)

data class LetterSentEvent(
        override val letterId: String,
        override val eventType: LetterEventType = LetterEventType.SENT
) : LetterMovementEvent(letterId, eventType)
```

Comment: not an answer to your question, but a hint to kotlin data class design: If the LetterEventType is important and linked to a certain sub-class, I would not make it changeable in the constructor ... just because you gave a default parameter, doesn't mean all users will omit  it ... use `data class XXX(...) : LetterMovementEvent(letterid, LetterEventType.XXX)`

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do something like that but I was getting the syntax wrong. :) I'll give that a try. I was just trying to add something to be able to verify behavior in this rudimentary example so wasn't too worried about tracking down the right syntax. (I'm new to kotlin, too!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're noticing @GoldFish, is the framework which is sourcing your aggregate based on the events it has published.
So, shortly put, you are seeing "Event Sourcing in action".

With the `@EventSourcingHandler` annotation in the `Letter` aggregate, you have effectively created the methods used to re-create an aggregate based on events.

Thus, if you send a command to cancel this aggregate's letter, it will firstly recreate the aggregate from the events. Only once this is resolved will the command actually be given to the `@CommandHandler` annotated method.

Hope this clarifies it for you @GoldFish!

Comment: Hi Steven, very helpful! It makes a lot of sense! But if that's the case then I wouldn't want to have `//complicated letter sending processes...` in the Event aggregate `@EventSourcingHandler` for `BeginSendLetterEvent`. I would only want to send that letter one time when the event is triggered the first time and the first time only. This routine might call a sub-process that triggers a side-effect of sending an email to a customer or something like that? So what's the right approach to that?

Comment: I may have found the answer to my question, and you might be able to confirm. Is that where `EventProcessors` come in https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/event-processing/event-processors

Comment: Actually it looks like sagas is what I might need? @Steven

Comment: Not necessarily a saga, but more so an event handling component which publishes a command back in to the aggregate. Saga's are a possible solution to that end, but a regular singleton with `@EventHandler` annotated methods would do just fine too.